# Can two routers be in same IP-range?

Tags: router, ipv4, lan

I'm having a modem with a built-in router, that connects to the internet through the 4g-network (productname: `Huawai`).

To this modem, I have a router connected in Lan1 (productname: `ZyXEL`). So my Huawai gets the internet and passes it on to my ZyXEL. I'm connected to the wireless-LAN on the ZyXEL. I'm using this setup, since the wireless-signal on the ZyXEL is stronger than on the Huawai (and the ZyXEL can't connect to the internet).

I have an IP-camera connected to the ZyXEL, that I would like to be able to access from an external IP-address. 
   I've Googled around, and it looks like, that I should do a port-forwarding to the given IP-address, in the router. I assume, that I have to do it in the Huawai-router, since that's the most-outer point of my network. However... I can access my Huawai-router by going to a browser and going to this IP:

```
192.168.1.1
```

But I can access my ZyXEL-router by going to a browser and going to this IP:

```
10.0.0.1
```

I can see that my own IP is 10.0.0.35 (which makes sense, since I'm connected to the ZyXEL-router.

So my questions are this:

1) Can I change the IP of the ZyXEL-router to be 192.168.1.2, so that the two routers are in the same IP-range? Or would that reck something?

2) Would it be better (and possible), if I just do a port-forward from my Huawai-router to the IP-cameras IP (which is 10.0.0.33, since that is connected to the ZyXEL). I mean, is that possible, since it's a different IP-range, or am I getting this all wrong?

3) Or am I trying to do something idiotic this way, by having two routers? Would it be better to simply throw the ZyXEL-router out, live with 2 bars instead of 4 and then set it all up with a single router?

4) And how do I know, which port it would be smart to do the forwarding from. I can find several articles on Google, that I should choose the port that I forward with caution - but I can find nothing about, which one(s) to choose?

Comment: You can probably set the ZyXEL as an AP and disable the routing functions. That way, you have the benefit of the ZyXEL Wi-Fi without the problems of double-NAT.

Comment: What is AP an abbreviation for? It sounds like a good idea...

Comment: AP is an access point. Your ZyXEL is a router with an AP, and, maybe, a switch combined. Most of these sorts of devices can be set to function as a wireless AP only, without the router function.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professional networks. Questions about home networks and consumer devices are considered off topic by this community and the devices as described sound like consumer devices. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [su]. If I am wrong about the devices, please edit to include the model numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change your Zytel routers IP to 192.168.1.2
2. Disable the DHCP on the Zytel and enable it on the Huawei.

This will allow the Huawei to handout/assign IP's + dns and gateway settings.

3. Your camera will also get a new ip in the 192.168.1.x range.

Now do the port forwarding for the new Cam ip on the Huawei.  Remember to consider security/access control.

4. If your Camera is wireless, you might also consider connecting it directly to the Huawei on a different wifi channel+ssid and leave your other devices on the Zytel.

Comment: Nice... In point 4 - why should I connect the wireless camera to the Huawei on a different wifi? What's the reasoning here?

Comment: #4 Less traffic on the Zytel,  if you stream video from CAM to another Wifi client, the traffic would traverse the same AP(Wifi Access Point) twice if you only use one AP.  With 2nd AP it would be. Cam -> AP1 -> Eth -> AP2 -> Client.